# Optimizing mcrypt encryption class further

Tags: object-oriented, php5, cryptography

The following is a very simple implementation of an `Encryption` class using mcrypt whereby the functions `encrypt` and `decrypt` are called **statically** by a PHP script on GET and on POST respectively:

```
class Encryption
{
    const CIPHER...

    static function encrypt($plaintext)
    {
        $td = mcrypt_module_open(self::CIPHER, "", self::MODE, ""); # <= move this outside?
        mcrypt_generic_init($td, self::KEY, 0);
        $ciphertext = mcrypt_generic($td, $plaintext);
        mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
        mcrypt_module_close($td);
        return base64_encode($ciphertext);
    }

    static function decrypt($ciphertext)
    {
        $td = mcrypt_module_open(self::CIPHER, "", self::MODE, ""); # <= repeated
        mcrypt_generic_init($td, self::KEY, 0);
        $plaintext = mdecrypt_generic($td, base64_decode($ciphertext));
        mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
        mcrypt_module_close($td);
        return $plaintext;
    }
}
```

Ignoring other aspects of this stripped down code, what I want to achieve is to reduce code duplication by perhaps moving `$td = mcrypt_module_open(self::CIPHER, "", self::MODE, "");` outside. Can this be done without combining the two methods or is what I have already at the optimum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually refactor most of the code into a separate function:

```
static function encryptdecrypt($text)
{
    $td = mcrypt_module_open(self::CIPHER, "", self::MODE, "");
    mcrypt_generic_init($td, self::KEY, 0);
    $text = mcrypt_generic($td, $text);
    mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
    mcrypt_module_close($td);
    return $text;
}

static function encrypt($plaintext)
{
    return base64_encode(encryptdecrypt($plaintext));
}

static function decrypt($ciphertext)
{
    return encryptdecrypt(base64_decode($ciphertext));
}
```

Comment: Nice try. But for decrypt, it uses the function `mdecrypt_generic` instead of `mcrypt_generic`. But I get your idea. Thanks!

Comment: @QuestionOverflow: Oh, I didn't spot that difference. You could send a flag into the function for which function to call.